# Element not interactable exception found in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I want to click on `Zero Cancellation` in Addons Tab at the top after the mouse hover. But it shows element is not interactable.. Please help me to solve this.
URL - https://www.spicejet.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Webdriver wait condition to wait for Visiblity of the element  which is why you are getting not element is not interactable exception

try below in your code

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
WebElement addon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()=\"Add-ons\"]"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(addon).perform();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
WebElement zeroCancellation = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//div[text()=\"Zero Cancellation\"]")));
zeroCancellation.click();
```